# Does calabash support iOS 8.4 on physical devices

Tags: calabash-ios

I have been using calabash-cucumber gem version 0.14.0 on iOS , I tried to install the app and test on a device that was recently upgraded to iOS 8.4 and it does not seem to work.

Will Calabash-cucumber work on iOS 8.4 physical devices if so what are the requirements (Gems , Xcode, calabash.framework versions and anything else) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  iOS 8 is supported.

- [Test Cloud Overview](https://testcloud.xamarin.com/test/5beae943-f52b-4ee2-b8b7-ad932654039e/)
- [Sample Scenario with iOS 8.4 devices showing](https://testcloud.xamarin.com/test/5beae943-f52b-4ee2-b8b7-ad932654039e/?step=0_0_0)

0.14.0 is supported but, you should (always) update to the most recent version of Calabash iOS - currently at 0.14.3.